# In React, is it ok for one state to be decided by another state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, if one state1 is track the mouseover of clientX and clientY, state2 get the value from state1 when you click. is that fine?

```
const [move,setMove]=useState([])
const [click,setClick]=useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const scrollPageY=()=>{
      setMove([window.clientX,window.clientY])
    }
    const clickPageY=()=>{
      setClick(click.concat(move))
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollPageY)
    window.addEventListener('click',clickPageY)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll',scrollPageY)
window.removeEventListener('click',clickPageY)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: I don't know if this logic is good for the same component but people used state to track state for parent and child component.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to set the state2 in a different useEffect. So every time move updates, the click will get the updated move value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setClick(click.concat(move))
},[move])
```